# (Unity) Can't acess class at same time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 methods

```
void InitializeSlot()
{
    if (hasItem)
    {
        ItemDatabase database = GameObject.Find("Inventory").GetComponent<ItemDatabase>();
        Item item = database.FetchItemById(itemId);

        Image image = transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.GetComponent<Image>();
        image.sprite = item.Sprite;
    }
}
```

And

```
void InitializeItem()
{
    ItemDatabase database = GameObject.Find("Inventory").GetComponent<ItemDatabase>();
    Item item = database.FetchItemById(itemId);
    itemId = item.Id;
}
```

Error:

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

In 2nd method at `itemId = item.Id;`

This is rly weird. Somehow i can't access to `ItemDatabase` component at same time from different classes.

First time i got error in line `image.sprite = item.Sprite;`.

Restarted Unity, now it's `itemId = item.Id;` line.

Both methods called at `void Start()`, but can't work together. Why?

FetchItemById

```
public Item FetchItemById(int id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < database.Count; i++)
    {
        if (database[i].Id == id)
        {
            return database[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Are they being run in parallel? Is `FetchItemById` considered thread-safe?

Comment: Uhm... Im new to c#, not sure what you mean by that. I added FetchItemById method to my question.

Comment: Maybe add how `InitializeSlot` and `InitializeItem` are being called also

Comment: They both called at `void Start()`, at game start.

Comment: Please show how. It sounds like a race condition. If `InitializeSlot` is called first `InitializeItem` fails and the other way around.

Comment: @Michael - do you mean a *race* condition..?

Comment: @CodeStranger, I did :) thanks

Comment: Item item = database.FetchItemById(itemId);
You first call FetchItemById(itemId) where haven't you assign itemId yet, 
and then you try to assign it to
 itemId = item.Id;

Comment: how is item.ID initialised? A NullReferenceException would indicate it's a variable that exists but has no value at the time of Start(). Is it a public field that is meant to be set in the editor?